# Updating data after inserting into database webservice

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a statement where it insert into my database but after inserting I would like to update my data in the table in `webservice`. How am I going to do it?

This is my code for **inserting data**:

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static void InsertStudentTransaction(string Name, string CLass, string NRIC, int StallNo, float AmountSpent, DateTime GetDate)
     {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString2"].ConnectionString))
     {

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT Into StudentTransactions (Name, CLass,NRIC,StallNo,AmountSpent, TimeDate) VALUES (@Name, @CLass, @NRIC, @StallNo, @AmountSpent, @GetDate)");

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "Name");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CLass", "CLass");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NRIC", "NRIC");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StallNo","StallNo");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AmountSpent", "AmountSpent");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeDate", "GetDate");

        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
[WebMethod]
        public static void UPDATEStudentTransaction(string Name, string CLass, string NRIC, int StallNo, float AmountSpent, DateTime GetDate)
         {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString2"].ConnectionString))
         {

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE StudentTransactions set Name=@Name, CLass=@CLass,StallNo=@StallNo,AmountSpent=@AmountSpent, TimeDate=@TimeDate WHERE <condition>");

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CLass", CLass);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NRIC", NRIC);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StallNo",StallNo);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AmountSpent", AmountSpent);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeDate", GetDate);

            command.Connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think its a good idea to Update the database from the Web Service Directly. You can get the User data from Webservice and, Pass that data to your Business Logic, Where you can properly validate every input from the User. If you just update the Input from the Webservice then, you might have a big problem later.

So, Get the Input from webservice, Create the Business logic and pass that to Business logic to handle everything. Including Validation, User input Normalization, Database Transactions every logic you should put there.

Comment: any examples for me to look thru?

Answer (score 0):

Does your `StudentTransactions` table have an `Identity` field as its primary key that you're wanting to return to the calling method to use in future Updates?

If so, look into returning the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.